The n-th number open problems
Some open problems in mathematics boil down to the question of defining the $n$-th term of a certain sequence for a specific $n$. For instance, the value of the $5$-th diagonal Ramsey number and the $10$-th Dedekind number are unknown. I would be grateful if you could provide other examples of such sequences and the smallest $n$ for which the values of these sequences are not determined.

One example I think of is Kissing Number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number

Another one is Van der Waerden numbers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_number

A good way to find such sequences is to check the OEIS: sequences with the keywords more, hard and bref can give you great examples!

The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences  (OEIS) has several thousand sequences with the keywords "hard" and "more"
